# Can't find scripts within partial views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an MVC partial view, that displays a pair of linked Kendo UI list boxes. Here is the code as I've written it so far:

```
@model MyProject.Areas.Items.Models.ItemGroupsViewModel

<label for="available">Available Items</label>
<label for="assigned">Assigned Items</label>
<br />

@(Html.Kendo().ListBox()
    .Name("available")
    .DataSource(dataSource =>
    {
        dataSource.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetItems", "Items").Data("function () { filterAssignedItems(); }");
        });
    })
    .Toolbar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Position(Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ListBoxToolbarPosition.Right);
        toolbar.Tools(tools => tools
            .MoveUp()
            .MoveDown()
            .TransferTo()
            .TransferFrom()
            .TransferAllTo()
            .TransferAllFrom()
        );
    })
    .ConnectWith("assigned")
    .Selectable(ListBoxSelectable.Multiple)
)

@(Html.Kendo().ListBox()
    .Name("assigned")
    .BindTo(Model.Items)
    .Selectable(ListBoxSelectable.Multiple)
)

@section JavaScript {
    <script>
        function filterAssignedItems() {
            var assignedItems = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Items));
            var availableItems = this.data().reduce(function (filtered, item) {
                if (!assignedItems.includes(item.ItemName)) {
                    filtered.push(item.ItemName);
                }
                return filtered;
            });

            return availableItems;
        }
    </script>
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that I can't get the first list box to see the JavaScript function that I defined. I've found several questions that address similar issues, but none seem to solve the problem that I'm having. I've tried a number of solutions to try and get this to work, including the following:

- Removing the `@section JavaScript` portion and directly using a `<script>` tag
- Simplifying the read.Action section to `read.Action("GetItems", "Items").Data("filterAssignedItems")`
- Doing both of the above at once

To this point, nothing has addressed the issue. What is the best way to approach this? Thanks!